# VBA; run macro (overwrite default shortcut) only in workbook that contains it

Tags: excel, vba

I am overwriting the paste shortcut (ctrl-v) with a macro to only paste values. 
However, I only want this to happen in the actual workbook the macro is in.

This is my code:

```
Sub paste_values_only()
If Not ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook Then Exit Sub
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

It seems to work, except that when I now ctr-v in another workbook, it just won't paste at all.. I want the ctrl-v to work like a normal paste action in another workbook.

To make things worse.. There's multiple workbooks that will have this paste-overwrite macro.

If there's an easier way to limit pasting in a certain workbook to values only, I'd be happy to hear about it too! I just want to prevent my colleagues pasting formatting/conditional rules/formulas/etc. into this workbook.

Comment: In order to help you on the issue, we maybe have to start from your code of 'overwriting the Paste shortcut'. To find a way of localizing it only for your workbook. Without seeing what you did, I am afraid I cannot know if it is even possible... I am thinking of using of an workbook event. In which code that "Exit Sub" does appear?

Comment: @FaneDuru, I edited to include my complete code. It's in a module.

Comment: But your code does not overwrites Ctrl + V. It only copies in the active cell the value of the Clipboard...  Do you say that after running of this piece of code, if you try using Ctrl + C followed by Ctrl + V in another workbook, it will  not copy format included? If you manually do that, it will behave as normal in the workbook where the code is, too. It will behave in that way only if you USE IT in order to Paste something from Clipboard (previously copied). Or you want to say that USING THIS CODE in another workbook it will strangely copy? It will not do anything because you told you that!

Comment: What do you want, in fact?

Comment: In the macro menu, under options, I made it trigger with the ctrl-v shortcut.

What I want is to prevent my colleagues from pasting any rich formatting (conditional rules, formating, formulas) into the file in question. 

This solution works, however any other workbook that is open also tends to trigger this macro now when using ctrl-v, while those workbooks need a normal paste functionality (with formulas etc)

Comment: Did you do that in code? Or manually?

Comment: So, you must learn VBA and do it by code. Otherwise, what you did is referring to Excel application, not to a specific workbook. You must define the shortcut in the `Workbook_Activate` event and reverse in the `Workbook_Deactivate` event... You must use for that the `Application.OnKey` function. If I will find some time, I will do that for you. But, it is better to learn it by yourself, I think...

Comment: Thanks!
I posted an answer that works for me at the moment, but a more elegant answer is always welcome! 
I'm trying to learn VBA indeed, but sometimes it's still a bit of a struggle!

Comment: And did you also create the same shortcut for your answer sub?

Comment: I did so far/for now, but I'm definitely reading into the function and events you suggested to use! I hadn't found that option yet!

Answer (score 0):

After some more elbow grease, I got a solution. Not very elegant, but it works:

Since all files that need to have this paste-protection have 'storage' in the name, I was able to limit the paste-limitation to these workbooks. Using `Selection.PasteSpecial` without features for the else clause I worked around the problem..

```
Sub paste_values_only()

Dim wbname As String

wbname = ActiveWorkbook.Name

If wbname Like "*storage*" Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
    Selection.PasteSpecial
End If

End Sub
```